# How can i set port for ffmpeg's output rtmp stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, port, streaming, rtmp

Can i set different ports for output rtmp streams using ffmpeg?

For example,
`ffmpeg -listen 1 -i rtmp://server0:port/live/key -c copy -f flv rtmp://server1/live/key -f flv rtmp://server2/live/key`

I need to set different ports for server 1 and server 2, but i have no idea about that. I will be very grateful if you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [tee muxer](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/tee.htm.gz).

Note:

- When using **tee**, we must **map** the video and the audio explicitly.

Use the following syntax:

`ffmpeg -listen 1 -i rtmp://server0:port/live/key -c copy -f tee -use_fifo 1 -map 0:v? -map 0:a? "[f=flv]rtmp://server1:port1/live/key|[f=flv]rtmp://server2:port2/live/key"`

- `-f tee` - uses tee muxer (split the output to two URLs).
- `-map 0:v? -map 0:a?` - maps the video and the audio (`?` is needed in case there is no video or no audio streams).
- `"[f=flv]rtmp://server1:port1/live/key|[f=flv]rtmp://server2:port2/live/key"`
  Split the output to two RTMP steams - `server1:port1` and `server2:port2`.
  `[f=flv]` select the FLV output format (for each).
- `-use_fifo 1` - Allows to compensate for different speed/latency/reliability of outputs.

---

### Testing

Here is an example for streaming synthetic video and audio to two FFplay instances:

Execute each command from a different terminal.

`ffplay -listen 1 -timeout 1000000 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/live/key`
`ffplay -listen 1 -timeout 1000000 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:6000/live/key`

Wait few seconds...

`ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 22050 -f tee -use_fifo 1 -map 0:v? -map 1:a? "[f=flv]rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/live/key|[f=flv]rtmp://127.0.0.1:6000/live/key"`

Please execute the test first, and let me know if it's not working.

Comment: thank you, now it works