# Streaming to multiple RTMP ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, cmd.exe, streaming, rtmp

I have this line to stream using a source to two outputs but im getting a signal for the first rtmp server but nothing for the second, what im doing wrong?

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4 -i hello.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "overlay=1700:1000,scale=1024:576" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://test -f flv rtmp://test2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If u check, im using two outputs  " -f flv rtmp://test -f flv rtmp://test2 "  The code works but it is only showing a signal in the first rtmp but not in the second, why?

Comment: You may use [tee muxer](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/tee.htm.gz). Check my [following answer](https://superuser.com/a/1726304/635712).